# z-index menu issue with bxslider in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, bxslider

I'm using a dropdown menu over the top of BX slider, but I simply cannot get it to show on top in IE7! I've searched everywhere for the answer, position relative just on the child item just doesn't seem to work. Please could someone help?

Here is the test page:http://theturning.co.uk/AMBA-NEW/

Ps - I have checked and tried the other posts on SO about IE z-index bug, but nothing works for me.

Comment: so `.submenu {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3000;
}` is not working, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found these issues are usually related to a parent container not having a z-index set. Try setting the z-index on the header element to 1

```
header {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I tested this in IE 7 and adding the z-index to the header element worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same kind of problem and I fixed as below,

consider the drop-down navigation menu as below,

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Set z-index for all child and grandchild elements as below,

```
ul#nav * { z-index:9999 } /* maximum zoom index as your wish */
```